# Multi-indexing failure

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, multi-index

I'm trying to create multi-indexing to my database, based on 2 columns: plant and date.
I want the column of "plant" to be the first one to be the outisde one and then the date.
I worked but for some reason the dates are not "aggregated" into one cell, like you can see here:

[image]

my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df_plants = pd.read_csv('Data_plants_26_11_2019.csv')
df_Nit=pd.read_csv('chemometrics.csv')

#create new colum which contains aonly the hour using lambda
df_plants['Hour']=df_plants['time'].apply(lambda time: time.split(' ')[1])
df_plants['date']=df_plants['time'].apply(lambda time: time.split(' ')[0])

#select only plants that their nitrogen content was checked
options=['J01B','J01C','J02C','J02D','J03B','J03C','J04C','J08C','J08D','J09A','J09C','J10A','J12C','J12D','J13A','J14A','J15A','J18A']
filter_plants=df_plants.loc[df_plants['plant'].isin(options)].copy()

filter_plants['Hour'] = pd.to_datetime(filter_plants['Hour']).apply(lambda x: str(x.hour) + ':00')


#index by plant ,date and hour
df_indices.set_index(['plant', 'date'], inplace=True)
df_indices.sort_index(inplace=True)
df_indices
```

**My end goal:to have the same dates  inside one cell.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This failure is expected output of `MultiIndex`, it `'remove'` (actually not display) only all levels without last, so here first level if duplicates.

If create 3 levels DataFrame it display like you need:

```
df_indices.set_index(['plant', 'date', 'Hour'], inplace=True)
```

---

```
df_indices = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('aaabbb'),
        'B':list('eeffee'),
        'C':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
        'D':[5,3,6,9,2,4]
})

df_indices.set_index(['A', 'B'], inplace=True)
print (df_indices)
     C  D
A B      
a e  1  5
  e  3  3
  f  5  6
b f  7  9
  e  1  2
  e  0  4

#temporaly display multi_sparse DataFrame (how data are real)
with pd.option_context('display.multi_sparse', False):
    print (df_indices)
         C  D
    A B      
    a e  1  5
    a e  3  3
    a f  5  6
    b f  7  9
    b e  1  2
    b e  0  4
```

---

```
df_indices = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('aaabbb'),
        'B':list('eeffee'),
        'C':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
        'D':[5,3,6,9,2,4]
})

df_indices.set_index(['A', 'B', 'C'], inplace=True)
print (df_indices)
       D
A B C   
a e 1  5
    3  3
  f 5  6
b f 7  9
  e 1  2
    0  4

#temporaly display multi_sparse DataFrame (how data are real)
with pd.option_context('display.multi_sparse', False):
    print (df_indices)
           D
    A B C   
    a e 1  5
    a e 3  3
    a f 5  6
    b f 7  9
    b e 1  2
    b e 0  4
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same result like in my original post, but now the plants are not indexed anymore

Comment: @Reut - OK, what is reason for need it? Because by default it is not possible, I try explain it in answer. Do you need special format in excel? Or some another reason?

Comment: sonehow now it worked with my original code and I added also hour: df_indices.set_index(['plant','date', 'Hour'], inplace=True)
df_indices.sort_index(inplace=True)
df_indices  , I feel confused, and I got again the SettingWithCopyWarning warning

Comment: @Reut - How are created `df_indices` ? There ia also added `.copy()` ?